# Jquery form validation plugin - how to submit with an extra step?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm currently using the [Jquery form validation plugin](http://docs.jquery.com/Plugins/Validation), and it works well when I followed it's form submission instruction on the webpage:

```
$("#form").validate({
    submitHandler: function(form) {
        form.submit();
    }
});
```

However, now I need to add a popup alert box after the users click the submit button, then they need to click a button on the popup box before the form being submitted.

So it needs to be:

1. fill in form, click submit button
2. pop up box shows up with a button, click that button
3. form submits

I have tried this but it triggers no response:

```
$("#form").validate({
    submitHandler: function(form) { 
        $('.popup').show();
        $('.popup').find('.button').click(function(){
            form.submit();
        });         
     }      
});
```

Comment: its a variable to call the popup div, but anyways i updated the code, sorry about the confusion.

Comment: I think you could probably use [namespaced event handlers](http://docs.jquery.com/Namespaced_Events) to help you wrangle the two-step you've got going. More or less, you need to prevent `submit.validated` from firing until *after* you've run `submit.unvalidated`. I'm not that well-versed in the jQuery validation plugin, though, so I'd have to look at it to figure it out. I do demonstrate namespacing during validation in [this answer](http://jsfiddle.net/userdude/CMmDF/), but be forewarned; there's a lot going on. Just look for the `event.value` syntax, though, and try to follow how that runs.

Comment: Here's the same validation fiddle [without most of the comments](http://jsfiddle.net/CMmDF/2/); the comments really help explain it I think, but also makes it hard to read. Looking at that code now, I would do some things differently. So hopefully there's nothing too double feature creature show going on with it.

Answer (score 0):

What is happening, is that pop up dialog box is displayed during the validation, and if validation has been successful, the form will be submitted before the user gets a chance to see the popup.

There is a similar problem perhaps [JavaScript Submithandler Issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7758280/javascript-submithandler-issue)

More ideally, you will need to change your form so the dialog perhaps appears before you actually submit the form.
i.e

1. Fill in Form
2. Click regular button that displays popup
3. Submit Form

This way you don't mix the validation and the popup together.

Answer (score 0):

Use the "on" command

http://api.jquery.com/on/

What happens is that your DOM element is created or visible AFTER the document is loaded. This will attach an event handler for any new DOM that appear.

Something like:

```
$('body').on('click','.button',function(){
    form.submit();
});
```

Here's an excellent article that explains what the ON does:

http://www.jquery4u.com/jquery-functions/on-vs-live-review/

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for all your help. What I ended up doing is adding a param `?submitted=true` in the form action, so its still the same page but with a param in the url. Then check the url to see if there is such a param and execute the popup accordingly. Not sure if its silly or not, but its the easiest way I could think of atm.

Answer (score 0):

Well, I guess you're really not needing this anymore. Oh well. I'll post it for posterity anyhow.

**HTML**

```
<form id="form">
    <fieldset>
        <legend>Please provide the following...</legend>
        <p>
            <label for="cname">Name (required, at least 2 characters)</label>
            <input id="cname" name="name" minlength="2" type="text" required />
        </p>
        <p>
            <label for="cemail">E-Mail (required)</label>
            <input id="cemail" type="email" name="email" required />
        </p>
        <p>
            <label for="curl">URL (optional)</label>
            <input id="curl" type="url" name="url" />
        </p>
        <p>
            <label for="ccomment">Your comment (required)</label>
            <textarea id="ccomment" name="comment" required></textarea>
        </p>
        <p><input class="submit" type="submit" value="Submit"/></p>
    </fieldset>
</form>
<div id="Achtung">
    <h1>Achtung!</h1>
    <p>You are about to provide the indicated information. Please be sure!</p>
</div>​
```

**Javascript**

```
(function env($, log) {
    $(function load() {
        var $form = $("#form"),
            form = $form[0],
            $Achtung = $('#Achtung'),
            valid = {submitHandler: Achtung};

        $form.validate(valid);

        function Achtung() {
            var buttons = [
                    {text: "Ok", click: ok},
                    {text: "Cancel", click: close}
                ],
                dialog = {modal: true, buttons: buttons};

            $Achtung.dialog(dialog);

            function ok(event, ui) {
                close(event, ui, "Submit Ok'd and will continue.");
                form.submit();
            }

            function close(event, ui, msg) {
                log(msg || 'Submit canceled by user.');
                $Achtung.dialog("close");
            }
        }

        // Just so the form does not submit; comment these
        // lines to verify it works.
        form.submit = function blocker(event, ui) {
            return !log('The form.submit() was triggered and canceled.');
        };

        fill();
    });

    // Nothing to see here...
    function fill(){
        var $els = $(':input[type!=submit], textarea'),
            d = ['oh', 'a@b.cd', location.href, 'oh'],
            $el;

        $.each(d, function fill(i, v){
            $el = $($els[i]);
            $el.is('input') ? $el.val(v) : $el.text(v);
        });
    }

})(jQuery, function z(){return !console.log.apply(console, arguments)});​
```

http://jsfiddle.net/userdude/jULBx/